# Can the standard math font be installed in Ubuntu to be used in inkscape?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, ubuntu, inkscape

i want to create a few sketches in inkscape, the font should match the standard math font used in my latex document. As i haven't done any changes in my document the standard font used for text is CM Roman. What is the corresponding math font and is it possible to install it system wide?

EDIT: From what i've gathered i need latin modern math. I have it already installed, but only as regular font, no italic option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For Ubuntu you can install the font package `fonts-cmu` (using `sudo apt install fonts-cmu`) which contains Computer Modern fonts (called 'CMU x').

However, in Inkscape you can also save the drawing as `PDF+LaTeX` (which you can select *after* you choose `File-Save As-Portable Document Format-Save`). In that case an extra file will be generated which instructs LaTeX to render text and math. Make sure you check the option `Use exported object's size`, otherwise a full page will be used by the drawing.

MWE:

```
% draw a star in Inkscape with some text underneath
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\input{drawing.pdf_tex}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: +1 for saving as pdf+latex. Two pitfalls I've come across: text size that latex renders not linked to what you use in ink scape which can be annoying. Also you won't have a standalone pdf of your figure which is sometimes needed e.g. for journal submission

Comment: @kabdulla for the second issue you can use the `standalone` documentclass (with otherwise the same MWE as here), which creates a pdf of the figure without a page around it (i.e. standalone), this works well with Inkscape figures.